# Error in pl/sql block has me stuck - Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match

Tags: oracle, plsql

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here, went over the code a few times tonight and I think I need a fresh set of eyes. I keep getting an error that states:

*Cause:    Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared
           return type of a result set  variable, or declared types of two Result
           Set variables do not match.
*Action:   Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable
           actually refers to during execution.

```
DECLARE
  cv_prod SYS_REFCURSOR;
  rec_payment dd_payment%ROWTYPE;

  TYPE pay2 IS RECORD (
    pledge_id dd_pledge.idpledge%TYPE, 
    amount NUMBER(8,2)
  );

  rec_payment2 pay2;
  lv_donor_id dd_donor.iddonor%TYPE := 303;
  lv_indicator_value CHAR(1) := 'd';
BEGIN
  IF lv_indicator_value = 'd' THEN
    OPEN cv_prod FOR
      SELECT idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod
      FROM dd_pledge inner join dd_payment USING (idpledge)
      WHERE iddonor = lv_donor_id
      ORDER BY idpledge, paydate;

    LOOP
      FETCH cv_prod INTO rec_payment;
      EXIT WHEB cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(rec_payment.idpledge  ||  ' '  ||  rec_payment.payamt  ||  ' '  ||  rec_payment.paydate  ||  ' '  ||  rec_payment.paymethod);
    END LOOP;
  ELSIF Lv_Indicator_Value = 's' THEN
    OPEN cv_Prod FOR
      SELECT idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod
      FROM dd_pledge INNER JOIN dd_payment USING (idpledge)
      WHERE iddonor = lv_donor_id
      GROUP BY idpledge;

    LOOP
      FETCH cv_prod INTO rec_payment2;
      EXIT WHEN cv_prod%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(rec_payment2.pledge_id  ||  ' '  ||  rec_payment2.amount);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Which line is the error reported against?

Comment: What are the columns in dd_payment?  Do these match the columns in your select statement?  Perhaps you need to change `rec_payment` to be of type `dd_pledge%rowtype` ?

Comment: The lack of aliases and table structures means this question is impossible to answer. We can't verify that the columns you're selecting match the columns of the record structure. More details required.

Comment: Possible problems: `fetch cv_prod into rec_payment;` and `fetch cv_prod into rec_payment2;`. Detailed resolution left to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're collecting the fields selected by your query into a record which doesn't have the same number and type of fields of your query.

For example, in your second cursor you're selecting the fields idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod:

```
OPEN cv_prod FOR
  SELECT idpledge, payamt, paydate, paymethod
  FROM dd_pledge INNER JOIN dd_payment USING (idpledge)
  WHERE iddonor = lv_donor_id
  GROUP BY idpledge;
```

And you're trying to put them into the rec_payment2 record:

```
FETCH cv_prod INTO rec_payment2;
```

But the type of this record is pay2, which is a record with only two fields:

```
TYPE pay2 IS RECORD (
  pledge_id dd_pledge.idpledge%TYPE, 
  amount NUMBER(8,2)
);
```